# No gradients to be propagated for Lambda layer

Tags: keras

I want to add a `Lamda` layer `sum = Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=1)(inputs)` but I don't want the gradients to be propagated. I want it to be treated like an `Input` layer. How can I do this in Keras? Something like a `no_grad` feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
sum = Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=1)(inputs)
sum_stop_grad = Lambda(lambda x: K.stop_gradient(x))(sum)
dense_1 = Dense(16)(sum_stop_grad)
...
```